# fatal error: Index out of range two custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two custom cells 
[image]

I configured them like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if searchActive{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry1 = auxiliar?[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: (entry1?.Logo)!))
        cell.shopName.text = entry1?.shopname

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
        return cell
    } else {
        if filteredArr == nil {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell

            let entry = shops[indexPath.row]

            cell.shopImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: entry.Logo))
            cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "design", for: indexPath) as! DesignTableViewCell
            let entry2 = filteredArr[indexPath.row]// error here 

            cell2.deignImage.hnk_setImage(from: URL(string: "http://jaee.com/upload/img/\(entry2.design)"))

            cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1 , alpha : 0.5)
            return cell2
        }
    }
}
```

but I get an error that index out of range. Can someone help me. I think it's because of numberOfRowsInSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchActive {
        return auxiliar!.count
    }
    return allShops.count
}
```

and here is how I save data. I'm filtering the shops. The shops with a design they should be in the `design` cell and the rest should be in `Cell`.

```
var info = Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : designImage )

self.shops.append(info)
self.filteredArr = self.shops.filter { $0.design != nil }
self.NofilteredArr =  self.shops.filter { $0.design == nil }
self.allShops = self.NofilteredArr + self.filteredArr
```

**UPDATE**
What I want is the design cell to be on the top only and the Cell is below it. 
[image]

Comment: `if searchActive { return auxiliar!.count; } else if filteredArr == nil { return allShops.count } else {return filteredArr.count}` because this needs to have the same logic as the one implemented in `cellForRow()` (or `cellForRow()` has to have the same logic as the on in `numberOfRowsInSection`).

Comment: Where is the index out of range error occurring? Is searchActive true or false?

Comment: check the updated question. The cells are only the design ones

Answer (score 2):

**Try this.**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchActive {
            return auxiliar!.count
        }else{
             if filteredArr == nil {
                shops.count
             }else{
                filteredArr.count
            }
        }
    }
```

i think your allShops is nil.

Comment: check the updated question. The cells are only the design ones

Comment: @leo0019 Where is the index out of range error occurring?please tell me.

Comment: it's not occurring anymore. Look at the image I updated in my question. The cells are all in one color and when I click on it I go to the selected shop. The cell with design is displayed but the ones without is bold( `Cell` is not displayed)

Answer (score 0):

In the cellForRowAt: method you have:

```
if searchActive{
    ...
} else {
    if filteredArr == nil {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

But in the numberOfRowsInSection: you have

```
if searchActive {
    ...
}
return ...
```

Probably you'll want to implement the same logic in the both methods.

Comment: check the updated question. The cells are only the design ones